# SQL column data won't display when hard-coded value is replaced with placeholder

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2005, placeholder

I am trying to replace place holders with user input.

When the user goes to run the report, a GUI dialog pops up asking them to specify the start date, end date, and customer ID.
I have several variables that store expressions to calculate certain outcomes. However, the data in the WHERE statements for the variables is hardcoded in, for example:

```
@InputWeight - (
    SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
  FROM IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots [ICPL]
     ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE 
    ([ICPL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND ([ICPL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR [ICPL].ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND (AR_Customers.CustomerCode = 904) 
)
```

This is problematic because the date will not always be the 24th of June and the customer code may not always be 904.

I created a variable called `@sID` and made it appear in the GUI dialog box. Then, I set `AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID`. So in the dialog box in the sID field if I enter 904 it will display the proper data.

The problem is, when I attempt to replace 904 with `@sID` in the `WHERE` statement for the variables, it doesn't display any data for that field.
This is how it looks:

```
@InputWeight - (
    SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
  FROM IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots [ICPL]
     ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE 
    ([ICPL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND ([ICPL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR [ICPL].ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND (AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID) 
)
```

When I have the variable expression as it is in my first example it displays correctly, but when I swap out 904 for `@sID`, nothing appears in that field. What am I doing wrong that it stops displaying the value necessary? Am I on the correct track?

I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2005.

Whole Code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Shrink Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Cost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Profit Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Proj Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @sID Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight - (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL]
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE 
 ([ICPL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND ([ICPL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR [ICPL].ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND (AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID) 
);
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;
SET @Cost  = ROUND((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
), 2);
SET @Profit  = (
 SELECT SUM(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2))
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
) - @Cost;
SET @Proj  = ROUND((@Profit) / (
 SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
 FROM IC_Products [PC] 
 INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
 ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
 INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
 ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
 ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
 LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
 ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
 WHERE (ICPL.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND (ICPL.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR ICPL.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1) AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124)) 
), 2)
;
SET @sID = 904;

SELECT DISTINCT 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , @Shrink AS [Shrink]
   , @Cost AS [Cost]
   , @Profit AS [Profit]
   , @Proj AS [Proj]
   , @sID AS [sID]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , AR_Customers.CustomerCode
 HAVING 
    (AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID)
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
```

Comment: . . Presumably, `@sID` is not being set to the value that you think it is being set to.

Comment: And what makes you so sure `@sID = 904`?

Comment: Try adding a line directly above that one in your code that says @sID = 904. See if that runs. if it does, then your problem is not in the SQL.

Comment: turn on the profile or just get what the dynamic SQL you app produced and run it manually to make sure what values are being used

Comment: @Amit because when I enter 904 in the dialog box in the sID field it displays the correct information for all of the other columns as if I had only entered 904 in the customer ID field.

Comment: So it works when you put in 904 but not for any other values?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy not necessarily, it only works when it is hard coded. If I put in 123 just like it is in the first example it would work, hypothetically. It just doesn't work when I try to use the variable (at)sID.

Comment: So when does it work, and when doesn't it? If you use values via the variable that are validated to "work" (by testing them hard coded), does it ever "not work"?

Comment: @Amit when I try other static values the report will run just fine, except for the one column where I input the new variable (at)sID.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm giving up. I simply don't understand you. Good luck

Comment: @Amit the first example works, the second example does not work. So if I were to hard code in any number that is in the system as a customer ID it would work. The problem comes into play when I try to use the placeholder (at)sID

Comment: So does it ever work with (at)sID? Is it that it "only likes certain values"??

Comment: @Amit no, thus far it has never worked with the placeholder sID. It may only like certain values but theoretically it should work with the placeholder, correct?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe it is, because if I run it with only inputting sID it displays the same information as if I had inputted the customer ID.

Comment: So back to my first question (the second comment up there, 14 minutes ago) - What makes you so sure @sID = 904? Have you validated that somehow? can you prove that?

Comment: @Amit sID doesn't always equal 904, sID can equal any int value that is a customer ID. But for this example, if I enter 904 in the sID dialog it displays the information for the customer 904. I can prove that it works because if I delete the variable sID and just use Customer Code, like I did before I needed the placeholders, it displayed the same data.

Comment: Unfortunately that proves nothing. Change your entire query to `SELECT @sID`. That will show you what it really holds

Comment: @Amit so SELECT DISTINCT (at)sID AS [sID]? If I do that it creates a new column displaying 904. Is that what you meant or did you mean something else. I am new to this.

Comment: The distinct and as parts were unnecessary, but that's good enough. With that I'd ask if you're sure you're using the correct type?

Comment: @Amit actually, I don't think it is equaling 904. Is [CustomerCode] = (at)sID not the proper way to go about it?

Comment: Didn't understand the last question. Is (at)sID and integer type?

Comment: @Amit yes, it is an integer, well it's set to decimal. Should I set it to int? I added my whole code to the question if that helps anything.

Comment: So that last code fragment, is that the one that works, or the one that doesn't? (And yes, using a decimal here is a huge mistake and a 99.999% chance the reason we've been chatting for the last hour)

Comment: Why do we always see "Where 1=1)" you don't need it. Also you have hard coded  AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124), that probably should also be a parameter.

Comment: @Amit the top two codes are only snippets of the whole code. The first one works, because it is hardcoded. The second one does not work because I try to use the variable. The last code fragment is the whole code attempting to use the variable as a placeholder, therefore it does not work. I changed it it from decimal to int and it still does not display.

Comment: @Chuck the only reason those one's are still hard coded is because I wanted to get one working with the placeholder first and then I was going to update the other variable expressions.

Comment: One last attempt, shot in the dark... replace `(AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID)` with `(AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID OR AR_Customers.CustomerCode = 904)` What happens now?

Comment: @Amit it displays the correct value, but if the customer ID is something else, such as 47 it still displays the value for 904.

Comment: Do you still have the line that sets (at)sID to 904 as it is in the last fragment in the question? cause if you do, where do you expect the 47 to go through? anyway, I got to go. Good luck

Comment: @Amit nope, it changed to 47. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clean up your query a bit, but it could still have errors, because I don't have your tables. But something like this might work:

```html
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Shrink Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Cost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Profit Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Proj Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @sID Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;
SET @sID = 904;

SELECT DISTINCT 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , @InputWeight - OriginalQuantitySum AS [Shrink]
   , ROUND((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * OriginalQuantitySum, 2) AS [Cost]
   , Profit AS [Profit]
   , Proj AS [Proj]
   , @sID AS [sID]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 left join (SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] as OriginalQuantitySum, SUM(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) as Profit,
    Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] as OriginalQuantitySum / SUM(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) as Proj)
    FROM IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] 
    ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
    INNER JOIN AR_Customers 
    ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
    INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [ICPL]
    ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
    ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
    WHERE 
    ([ICPL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } AND ([ICPL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR [ICPL].ProductionDate Is Null)) 
   AND (AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID)) GB
  on GB.CustomerCode = AR_Customers.CustomerCode
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)
 and AR_Customers.CustomerCode = @sID) 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , AR_Customers.CustomerCode
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
```

Comment: this will not work because purchase cost, input weight, product cost, and supplier ID are dynamic values and will not always be those numbers. Those numbers vary based on what the user inputs.

Comment: You should pass those as parameters, which should work.

Comment: pass what as parameters? Each supplier ID? How would I go about doing that?